# Combatible firmware for old S7

Tags: samsung, device-firmware

I got an old s7. Looking through the settings it says:

Model Number: SM-G930FD
Build Number MMB29K.G930FXXU1BPIF
Baseband Verion:G930FXXU1DQE8

I am trying to find a compatible firmware to manually install, since when I told the phone to search for updates it does not find anything. The device has Android 6.0.1 with September 2016 security update which looks very insecure to use.

I am trying to find a compatible update, preferably based on android 8 and released during the last two months. However I am not sure about what to use.

Another strange thing is that when I try to find the existing firmware on the device I cannot find it when searching for SM-G930FD. However I do find [this entry](https://updato.com/firmware-archive-select-model/?record=9115ABEC80D911E69B2DFA163EE8F90B) for SM-G930F with PDA G930FXXU1BPIF. Also if I enter download mode the phone shows:
PRODUCT NAME: SM-G930F
!!

I am not sure what to make of this. Is the phone a G930F or a G930FD? And what should match when I try to find an official firmware that should match this phone's hardware?

Comment: Your baseband version seems to be 1 character short?

Comment: Also, to be sure about your model, can you 1) check that if you have a dual-SIM tray, and 2) download [Phone INFO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) and obtain the full firmware info?

Comment: Had a typo, updated correct baseband.

Comment: Phone Info app shows the phone model as `SM-G930F / Galaxy S7 (Dual SIM)` ?!

Comment: I guess the internet just has no idea about this particular build/baseband combo, hence it can't be found anywhere. Nevertheless I'm going to submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SM-G930F` is the single-SIM variant and `FD` the dual-SIM variant. If it says `FD` in Settings, and - as a more concrete proof - can also take/read 2 SIMs (`FD` has a different SIM tray), then you can be sure it's an `FD`.

The two actually share the same hardware otherwise, hence you'll see `G930F` in Download Mode. In fact, 1) there had been users reporting that flashing `F` firmware on `FD` is possible and doesn't remove dual-SIM functionality (more on that in [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/how-to/galaxy-s7-dual-sim-discussion-t3316311)), and 2) it's even possible to convert an `F` to an `FD` with certain steps and swapping the SIM tray for one from `FD`.

As for firmware, any [G930FD firmware](https://updato.com/firmware-archive-select-model/?q=SM-G930FD&rpp=15&order=date&dir=desc&exact=1) listed will work, though for the best customized experience you'll want to find one that matches or at least close to your geographical region.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to successfully upgrade the phone with [this firmware](https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-s7/firmware/SM-G930FD/INS/download/G930FXXU5ESD2/273248/). I selected that one because the bootloader code `U5E` was closer to the existing one `U1B` than the other ones that started with `S` even though they were more recent.

Answer (score 2):

SM-G930FD and SM-G930FD are all models of the Samsung Galaxy S7. See [Samsung Galaxy S7 Specifications](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s7-7821.php).

> Versions: G930F (Global); G930FD (Global; Southeast Asia); G930W8 (Canada)

On the Misc section of the above link:

> Models:   SM-G930F, SM-G930A, SM-G930P, SM-G930V, SM-G930T, SM-G930R, SM-G930F, SM-G930FD, SM-G930W8, SM-G930S, SM-G930L, SM-G930K, SM-G9300

For firmwares, you can verify [here](https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-s7/firmware/SM-G930FD/) for G930FD and [here](https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-s7/firmware/SM-G930F/) for G930F. Check if your country is among those with new firmwares.